# How to render html content with erb tags in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm writing simple cms engine, and having a problem with dynamic content rendering, for example I prepare some page content with erb tags and helpers, how I can evaluate them in my view?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example to clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you want to store snippets that contain ERB markup somewhere and at runtime evaluate them in your real templates of your rails app.

in this case, i think you will have to invoke ERB by hand. this is not really hard:

```
require 'erb'
name = "Rasmus"
template_string = "My name is <%= name %>"
template = ERB.new template_string
puts template.result # prints "My name is Rasmus"
```

read more in this nice writeup http://rrn.dk/rubys-erb-templating-system

Comment: Thanks, good article, but I've have helper methods and route links in my template.

Comment: if you look at the documentation here http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result you can see, that you can pass a context to `result` that is used for binding calls. if you pass `this` there should be no problem with routes and helper methods.

Comment: yep, I've passed my controller binding. but got strange "undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass" on line with link_to helper.

Comment: i don't know how much other magic is involved in rendering rails templates. you might have to look it all up in ActionView. i guess that is a completely different thing from what you asked.

Comment: Template - it's just a page content, some html and erb tags with ruby code and helpers.

Comment: are you executing this in a request response cycle?

Comment: i think the trick here would be to simply put the `template.result(binding)` part directly into your view. this way, you can call every viewhelper method that would be available to you in a normal rails view.

Comment: don't forget to mark your answer as complete for others to see that there is no need to help.